# Pegar ID do registro criado Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho o código abaixo para criação de um relatório:

```
$this->repository->create($request->all());
return response()->json(['sucesso' => 'Relatorio cadastrado com sucesso.']);
```

Como faço para pegar o ID do registro criado e mandar junto na resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guarde o objeto numa variável, neste caso o `$new`, tente o seguinte:

```
$new = $this->repository->create($request->all());
return response()->json(['sucesso' => 'Relatorio cadastrado com sucesso. ID: ' .$new->id]);
```

Comment: Perfeito @Miguel obrigado! (Aguardarei o tempo mínimo para marcar como correta)

Comment: De nada @RaylanSoares, ainda bem que resolveu